# PHP character encoding hell reading csv file with fgets

Tags: php, encoding, fgets

I have a web site that receives a CSV file by FTP once a month.  For years it was an ASCII file. Now I'm receiving UTF-8 one month then UTF-16BE the next and UTF-16LE the month after that.  Maybe I'll get UTF-32 next month.  Fgets returns the byte order mark at the beginning of the UTF files.  How can I get PHP to automatically recognize the character encoding?  I had tried mb_detect_encoding and it returned ASCII regardless of the file type.  I changed my code to read the BOM and explicitly put the character encoding into mb_convert_encoding.  This worked until the latest file, which is UTF-16LE.  In this file it reads the first line correctly and all subsequent lines show as question marks ("?").  What am I doing wrong?

```
$fhandle = fopen( $file_in, "r" );
if ( fhandle === false )
    {
    echo "<p class=redbold>Error opening file $file_in.</p>";
    die();
    }

$i = 0;
while( ( $line = fgets( $fhandle ) ) !== false )
{
$i++;

// Detect encoding on first line. Actual text always begins with string "Document"
if ( $i == 1 )
    {
    $line_start = substr( $line, 0, 4 );
    $line_start_hex = bin2hex( $line_start );
    $utf16_start = 'fffe4400';
    $utf8_start = 'efbbbf44';
    if ( strcmp( $line_start, 'Docu' ) == 0 )
        { $char_encoding = 'ASCII'; }
    elseif ( strcmp( $line_start_hex, 'efbbbf44' ) == 0 )
        {
        $char_encoding = 'UTF-8';
        $line = substr( $line, 3 );
        }
    elseif ( strcmp( $line_start_hex, 'fffe4400' ) == 0 )
        {
        $char_encoding = 'UTF-16LE';
        $line = substr( $line, 2 );
        }
    elseif ( strcmp( $line_start_hex, 'feff4400' ) == 0 )
        {
        $char_encoding = 'UTF-16BE';
        $line = substr( $line, 2 );
        }
    else
        {
        echo "<p class=redbold>Error, unknown character encoding. Line =<br>", $line_start_hex, '</p>';
        require( '../footer.php' );
        die();
        }
    echo "<p>char_encoding = $char_encoding</p>";
    }

// Convert UTF
if ( $char_encoding != 'ASCII' )
    {
    $line = mb_convert_encoding( $line, 'ASCII', $char_encoding);
    }

echo '<p>'; var_dump( $line ); echo '</p>';
}
```

Output:

```
    char_encoding = UTF-16LE

string(101) "DocumentNumber,RecordedTS,Title,PageCount,City,TransTaxAccountCode,TotalTransferTax,Description,Name
"

string(83) "???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"

string(88) "????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"

string(84) "????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"

string(80) "????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"
```

Answer (score 5):

Explicitly pass the order and possible encodings to detect, and use strict parameter. Also
please use `file_get_contents`, if the file is in UTF-16LE, `fgets` will screw it up for you.

```
<?php
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$input = file_get_contents( $file_in );

$encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $input, array(
    "UTF-8",
    "UTF-32",
    "UTF-32BE",
    "UTF-32LE",
    "UTF-16",
    "UTF-16BE",
    "UTF-16LE"
), TRUE );

if( $encoding !== "UTF-8" ) {
    $input = mb_convert_encoding( $input, "UTF-8", $encoding );
}
echo "<p>$encoding</p>";

foreach( explode( PHP_EOL, $input ) as $line ) {
    var_dump( $line );
}
```

The order is important because UTF-8 and UTF-32 are more restrictive and UTF-16 is extremely permissive; pretty much any random
even length of bytes are valid UTF-16.

The only way you will retain all information, is to convert it to an unicode encoding, not ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to just convert everything to UTF-8 or ASCII (not quite sure from the code you posted if you're trying to convert everything to UTF-8 or ASCII)

```
$utf8Line = iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $line ), 'UTF-8', $line );
```

or...

```
$asciiLine = iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $line ), 'ASCII', $line );
```

You can leverage `mb_detect_encoding` to do the heavy lifting for you

Comment: Unfortunately mb_detect_encoding seems to return "ASCII" for some of the UTF files.

Comment: whoops, missed that part of the question.. going back to drawing board

Comment: but ascii is a subset of unicode (the first 255 decimal), so they should convert easily. just convert to ascii and dont use multi-byte strings. Oh, and have you thought about maybe yelling at the people supplying the FTP data?

Comment: I have tried yelling at the people supplying the file, but yelling at  a county agency is like talking to a brick wall.  They just do whatever they do!

Comment: By "just convert to ASCII", do you mean some other technique that mb_convert_encoding() that I am now using?

Comment: I tried replacing mb_convert_encoding with iconv. Iconv returns empty strings, at lease for the UTF-16LE file.

Comment: I discovered that my problem with the UTF16-LE file is how it handles the line end characters.  The line end is 0D 00 0A 00. Fgets is tacking the last 00 onto the beginning of the next line :(