# Encode CSV file in php, to import in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv file, in Greek. The encoding of the file is ASCII. My DB encoding is set to utf8_general_ci. How can i convert each row in utf8 so as to be stored in the DB?

```
$file = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'],"r");

$i=0;

while(! feof($file)){
    $load = fgetcsv($file);
    foreach($load as $csv){
        $cv = explode(";", $csv);
        if($i>=10){
            $row = $students->addStudent($cv[3], $cv[2], $cv[4], NULL, $_COOKIE['school_id'], $_COOKIE['class_id']);
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Opening the csv file, in text editor and changing the format, is not applicable, as the visitor should do it, and most probably they don't know how.

also tried

```
/*switch(mb_detect_encoding ($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])){
    case "ASCII":
        echo "ASCII";
        $file = iconv("ASCII", "ISO-8859-7", $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
    break;

    case "UTF-8":
        echo "UTF-8";
        $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    break;

    default:
        $file = utf8_encode($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
    break;

}*/
```

but no results

Comment: fgetcsv() return an array, you don't have to explode its result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while(! feof($file)){
    $csv = utf8_encode(fgets($file));
    $cv = explode(";", $csv);
    if($i>=10){
        $row = $students->addStudent($cv[3], $cv[2], $cv[4], NULL, $_COOKIE['school_id'], $_COOKIE['class_id']);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed..i can not store students' name in DB

Comment: I am trying with iconv("ASCII" "UTF-8", $file);
It returns the names on the page, it stores on DB but fields (name, surname, father's name) are empty, NOT NULL

Comment: You should try to remove the   `foreach($load as $csv){` loop from the code and then try again, I really don't understand its use in this context.

Comment: no, doesn't do the work..this is a piece of the result..
±Γ©Γ¨Γ¬ΓΌΓ² Γ¬Γ§Γ΄Γ±ΓΎΓ―Γ΅;ΓΓ°ΓΎΓ­Γ΅Γ¬Γ― Γ¬Γ‘Γ¨Γ§Γ΄Γ;ΒΌΓ­Γ―Γ¬Γ‘ Γ¬Γ‘Γ¨Γ§Γ΄Γ;ΒΌΓ­Γ―Γ¬Γ‘ Γ°

Comment: Take help from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407584/php-character-encoding-hell-reading-csv-file-with-fgets

Comment: as soon as they say, ascii is a subset of utf-8, why Greek letters are not stored in MySQL properly?? Stil hasn't figured out....

Answer (score 0):

I will encode the file, from greek-charset to utf-8 and then store them in DB.
Maybe, it wasn't working because i didn't have the correct encoding, this works

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
$file = iconv('ISO-8859-7','UTF-8', $file);
file_put_contents($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], $file);

$filed = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'],"r");
$i=0;

while(! feof($filed)){
$load = fgetcsv($filed);
foreach($load as $csv){
    if($i>=10){
        $cv = explode(";", $csv);
        $row = $students->addStudent($cv[3], $cv[2], $cv[4],'', $_COOKIE['school_id'], $_COOKIE['class_id']);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The best way, you use array_map() function. I.e.

```
$array = array_map("utf8_decode", $array);
```