# php importing google contacts csv file

Tags: php, csv, import

After reading csv file,I get questions marks in the response.
check the below image for more reference.

[image]

I'm trying to import google contacts to my web app.This is my code

```
$csvAsArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));
        foreach($csvAsArray as $arr){
            var_dump($arr);
        }
```

where $tmpName is file location.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `print_r` first. Is it just that your response is formatted incorrectly with question marks? Or are you not getting a proper return at all?

Comment: Response is formatted incorrectly.please check the screenshot.

Comment: Please see this answer, seems like a character encoding issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407584/php-character-encoding-hell-reading-csv-file-with-fgets

Comment: Nope,that dint help.I have UTF-8 encoding in response

Comment: Weird, do you mind uploading a portion of the csv (removing private information), and I can test for you?

Comment: sure check this.  0 => string '�' (length=1)
  1 => string '�' (length=1)
  2 => string '�' (length=1)
  3 => string '�' (length=1).........
  27 => string '�*� �' (length=5)
  28 => string '�a�k�h�i�l�t�h�e�w�a�y�@�g�m�a�i�l�.�c�o�m�' (length=43)
  29 => string '�' (length=1)
  30 => string '�' (length=1)
  31 => string '�' (length=1)
  32 => string '�
�' (length=3)

Comment: Lol no that won't work. I mean can you upload a portion of the actual CSV file (remove private information). This is definitely a character encoding issue.

Comment: oops sorry.check this out   https://gist.github.com/chintusoni/d23b7f3585d233e9ac0c

Comment: I was able to parse that successfully. Maybe try using this tool here: http://i-tools.org/charset to convert your original document to utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Using iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $fileContent) on my whole CSV solved the problem for me.