# UTF-8 Hebrew encoding and big question marks

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have read a lot of articles but still i dont get it

Im importing text from file using

```
$fp = fopen($storagename, 'r');
while ( !feof($fp) ){
    $line = fgets($fp, 2048);
    $delimiter = "\t";
    $data = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);

    print_r($data);
}
```

For displaying numbers and english charachters correctly i had to use

```
str_replace("\x00", '', $data[7])
```

But now trying to display hebrew charachters ends up looking like
�

I have tried converting with iconv/mb_convert_encoding/utf8_decode/encode
Nothing helps..

Any assistance will be great

Comment: You can't just strip random bytes from a text file in order to display it, that's not how text encoding is supposed to work. You absolutely need to determine the encoding of the text file (I guess it could be some variation of UTF-16), know the encoding of your app and use proper conversion functions like mb_convert_encoding() or iconv().

Comment: well i dont have this data, how can i find out the encoding of the txt file ?

Comment: You'll have to guess. Load it in a good editor or in your browser and change the encoding until it looks good.

Comment: It looks good when i open it this is not my problem ...

Comment: Alright, tell me what editor you are using and I'll try to google how to find out current file encoding in that editor.

Comment: Related answer: [PHP character encoding hell reading csv file with fgets](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14413222/3439404)

Comment: JosefZ if im using this function it turns out encoding = false
Any other suggestions ?

Comment: When i open the file in notepad++ it looks like the encoding is: UCS-2 little Endian

Comment: @JosefZ Although the question you link makes a better use than average, `mb_detect_encoding()` is not specially helpful to auto-detect encoding. It merely seeks for invalid byte sequences.

Answer (score 3):

UCS-2 is an older version of UTF-16 so you should probably try both (auto-detect text encoding is not a bullet-proof job).

We have the source encoding. We can speculate the target encoding is UTF-8 (because it's the sensible choice in 2016 and your question is actually tagged as UTF-8). So we have all we need.

We should first remove non-standard raw byte manipulations (e.g. remove `str_replace("\x00", '', $data[7])` and similar code). We can then do a proper conversion. If you use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding), an initial approach could be:

```
$delimiter = "\t";
$fp = fopen($storagename, 'r');
while ( !feof($fp) ){
    $line = mb_convert_encoding(fgets($fp, 2048), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE');
    $data = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);
    print_r($data);
}
```

You can check the list of [supported encodings](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php).

But we have a potential problem here: there's no way to tell `str_getcsv()` about the file encoding so it's unlikely that it will recognise your UCS-2 line endings.

You can try different solutions depending of the size of the CSV file. If it's small, I'll simply convert it at once. Otherwise, I'll have a look at [stream_get_line()](http://php.net/stream_get_line):

> This function is nearly identical to fgets() except in that it allows end of line delimiters other than the standard \n, \r, and \r\n, and does not return the delimiter itself.

It'd be something like this:

```
$ending = mb_convert_encoding("\n", 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
$line = mb_convert_encoding(stream_get_line($fp, 2048, $ending), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE');
```

This should work with both Unix line endings (`\n`) and Windows ones (`\r\n`).